# Forumla to look for a cells contents then do this or that

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to add a formula to a cell that already references an external page.

The worksheet is set out like so:

The first row is a years, some 2010, some 2011.
Under them is a list product values. So 242352 etc etc...

The tricky part is that some cells have different exchange rates for them and as this is updated each month on another separate sheet, new exchange rates need to be imputed manually.

Is there a formula that would, look for the cell above it and if it contains 2011 say, reference the exchange rate in another sheet or if 2010 use a different one... etc

Comment: could you add a screenshot of what your data look alike?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a kludgy IF syntax such as:

```
=IF(B$1=2010, FirstFormula, IF(B$1=2011, SecondFormula, IF(B$1=2012, ThirdFormula, "")))
```

Or you could use a CHOOSE method:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(B$1, {2010,2011,2011}, 0), FirstFormula, SecondFormula, ThirdFormula)
```